# Printing ( ) for sub trees in pre-order

Tags: java, algorithm

I need to print ( and ) for the subtrees of pre-order:

```
       A
     /   \
    B     G
   / \
  C   P
   \
    E
```

I tried to do:

```
public StringBuilder preOrder(StringBuilder string) {
        string.append(value);
        if (left!=null || right!=null)
            string.append("(");
        if (left != null){
            left.preOrder(string);
        }
        if (left!=null && right!=null)
            string.append(")");
        if (right != null){
            right.preOrder(string);
        }
        return string;
    }
```

However, the result comes out:

A(B(C(E)P)G

Instead of:

(A(B(C(E)P)G))

What is wrong?

**EDITED:**

it has to be

(A(B(C(E())P())G()))

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: You have to start with empty **()**. Start with **(** and before the return, close with **)**. If the tree is empty, you should have () right?
Can you give us more information?

Comment: Yes. If it has one element it will be (A) for isntance

Comment: You open the brackets if at least one subtree is non-null, you only close them if both aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find these two lines suspect:

```
if (left!=null && right!=null)
    string.append(")");
if (right != null){
    right.preOrder(string);
}
```

You're inserting a right bracket **then** processing the right child. Where's the right bracket after the right child?

I imagine this would work:

```
if (right != null){
    right.preOrder(string);
}
if (left != null || right != null)
    string.append(")");
```

And then you also need to (separately) account for the surrounding brackets (the above should give you `A(B(C(E)P)G)`, you need to add the surrounding `()` in the calling function).

**In response to your edit:**

Since you want to add brackets regardless of having children,
just remove `if (left != null || right != null)` in both cases:

```
public StringBuilder preOrder(StringBuilder string) {
    string.append(value);
    string.append("(");
    if (left != null){
        left.preOrder(string);
    }
    if (right != null){
        right.preOrder(string);
    }
    string.append(")");
    return string;
}
```

Comment: I edited my question - I need also for P and G set that they have empty children. Sorry! I voted up in any case